# Ожидание полной загрузки страницы Jsoup

Tags: java, ajax, jsoup

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь парсингом сайта средствами Jsoup, хочу спарсить страницу, но она не успевает прогрузиться полностью, как я получаю страницу, так как страница подгружается ajaxом. http://www.flashscore.com/match/fJ12apqa вот пример страницы. Получаю много "Loading...".

Comment: Дело не в "не успевает", а в "вообще и не собирается". То, что подгружается через AJAX - грузится браузером благодаря скриптам на JavaScript. Ваша программа на Java просто забирает страницу. Никаких скриптов не запускает. При парсинге эти загрузки нужно имитировать или в более сложном случае - скармливать JavaScript - движку

Comment: А не подскажите как это реализовать? Selenium?

Comment: В двух словах не скажу. Сам пока такое не делал, но направлений несколько: 1. Найти по коду запросы (если они не слишком сложно собираются) и выполнять их из вашего кода; 2. Имитация работы браузера (или ваш вариант с Selenium или варианты отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/q/19759421/3349900

Comment: В общем я разобрался, использовал второй вариант, загружал драйвером, парсил jsoup. Поставил условие, на ожидание элемента в 10 секунд(максимум), хотя по факту больше одной секунды нигде не было, ну и задержку между запросами 5 секунд